# Passlock design in Android

Tags: android, layout

I am stuck in app locker.
Pleas help me to figure out.
Here I use a background image in that there are 9 holes. I need to put images on each hold for password. I try much but each time images are not on the same places on different screens or display devices. Please give me some demo or tutorial. Thank you!

Actually I want to design like the below picture, where the background image is constant with holes, and I want to put on each hole with different pig image. But the problem is I don't know how to design layout for accurate pig position and another important thing is that if the display screen is different, does the layout design work?

[image]

Comment: Sorry this realy is a little bit unclear. How exactly is the unlocker implemented? how about some code? The image doesn't help at all either.

Comment: Actually, the image above is the background of the application, where I want to put some little images on the holes, when the user click on each images from the hole then I will disappear the little clicked image. This is mostly like password locker like iPhone.